# Where are the exceptions for websites that use expired SSL certificates stored in my pc?

Tags: facebook, logging, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

We had a situation of an expired SSL certificate on our test-site and could not log in. However, log in through facebook worked after asking if you trust the site with an expired SSL certificate. After confirming that you trust it the regular log in also worked. After deleting the all info in the browser it did not work again. I thought that the exception is not saved in the browser, but it seems like it is, so:

**is the security exception stored in browser or somewhere else in the PC? How to access it?**

Comment: Which browser were you using?

Comment: Primarily Chrome, but when I confimed that I trust the site on Chrome, I still coul not log in witout problems from other browsers using the same machine. Thant would suggest that the exception is stored in browser memory, but I wanted to make sure?

Does it have any difference which browser specifically was I using? Will IE bahave differently on Windows than other browsers?

Comment: (Voted to move to SuperUser, by the way.)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, Chrome and IE will forget about this exception when you close them.

Firefox uses its own certificate verification mechanism. You can check the list of certificates in Options -> Advanced -> Certificates -> View Certificates. You can then manage the exception in the Servers tab.
If you've added them yourself, you'll probably have a specific server name in the Server column.

You'll also find other exceptions there (e.g. "DigiNotar Cyber CA" for "*"), these are *negative* exceptions (distrusting that CA), don't remove them. In this case, if you click on "View...", the window title will say something like "Builtin Object Token:Explicitly Distrust ...".